# Ошибка при запросе к БД через EntityFrameworkCore C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Подскажите по работе с Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

У меня есть База Данных с номерами телефонов:

id

nomerPhone

где nomerPhone  - уникальное значение

и когда я добавляю в БД номер телефона дублирующий, у меня возникает ошибка, как ее можно будет обойти?
вот мой запрос на добавление:

```
async public Task AddPhoneBd(List<string> listPhone)
{

    //подключаемся к БД
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {

        var data = listPhone.Select(phone => new StructureBd() { nomerPhone = phone });                
        db.base_wa.AddRange(data);

        //сохраняем изменения в БД
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это значит, что в этой сущности поле номера телефона настроено как уникальное т.е. не может дублироваться. А это значит изначально так было задумано. Если сейчас требования изменились, измените настройки этого поля.

Comment: Вам либо надо убрать настройку уникальности, либо добавить еще одну таблицу в которой можно будет делать несколько записей привязанных к одному и тому же номеру телефона.

Comment: Вам что нужно-то? Записать в БД все новые номера телефонов, игнорируя ошибки дубликатов?

Comment: _Вам что нужно-то? Записать в БД все новые номера телефонов, игнорируя ошибки дубликатов?_ Да именно это и нужно, у меня есть список номеров телефонов и при добавлении в БД нужны только уникальные номера телефонов... А когда добавляется дубликат у меня выходит ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо переспросить у базы какие номера уже есть и не вставлять их:

```
async public Task AddPhoneBd(List<string> listPhone)
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var existing = db.base_wa
           .Where(e => listPhone.Contains(e.nomerPhone))
           .Select(e => e.nomerPhone);
        
        var data = listPhone
           .Except(existing)
           .Select(phone => new StructureBd() { nomerPhone = phone });  
          
        db.base_wa.AddRange(data);

        //сохраняем изменения в БД
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

По просьбам добавляю вариант на linq2db с использованием временных таблиц. Для этого придется поставить расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

```
class Phones
{
   [Column] public string nomerPhone;
}

async public Task AddPhoneBd(List<string> listPhone)
{
    var phonesData = listPhone.Select(n => new Phones { nomerPhone = n });

    using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
    using (var l2db = db.CreateLinqToDBConnection())
    using (var tempTable = await l2db.CreateTempTableAsync("#Phones", phonesData)       
    {
        var queryToInsert = 
           from d in tempTable
           from p in db.base_wa.LeftJoin(p => p.nomerPhone == d.nomerPhone)
           where p == null
           select d;
           
        await queryToInsert.InsertAsync(db.base_wa.ToLinqToDBTable(),
          d => new StructureBd() { nomerPhone = d.nomerPhone });
    }
}
```

Comment: Практически всегда на подобный вопрос дают такой ответ. Увы, он не совсем правильный. Ведь другой процесс/поток может успеть изменить БД в промежутке между двумя этими запросами. В итоге может вылететь исключение.

Comment: Это нормальное решение, если с БД работает одно-единственное приложение (причём в один поток). Иначе нужно обязательно перехватывать исключения и реагировать на них.

Comment: Дать решение на linq2db?

Comment: Лично моё мнение: linq2db - шикарная вещь. И порекламировать её стоит.

Comment: _Ведь другой процесс/поток может успеть изменить БД в промежутке между двумя этими запросами._ Как тогда этого можно избежать? Может как-то лочить БД?

Comment: @srgo211 - Могу лишь повторить ещё раз: перехватывать исключения (которые будут бросаться в методе SaveChange)

Comment: Поправил ответ и добавил использование linq2db.